# authenticate only superuser

Tags: python, django

authenticate() function is only authenticating superuser

I had tried using simple search but it's not gonna use login() function then and not gonna check that user is active or not

'''

```
def Login_View(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        paswrd = request.POST['pwd']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=paswrd)

        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                name = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
                request.session['username'] = username
                return redirect('/dashboard/',{'name':name.username})
                # return render(request,'dashboard_app/index.html',{'name':name.username})
            else:
                 return render(request, 'login_app/index.html', {'error_message': 'Your account has been disabled'})
        else:
            return render(request, 'login_app/index.html', {'error_message': 'Invalid login'})
    return render(request, 'login_app/index.html')
```

'''

I want to login all user that is in the database either they are simple user or superuser

Comment: How are you creating those non-super users? Assuming you created the superusers via the manage command, I bet your problem is in the code you used to create the others.

Comment: I am adding them by using usercreation form

Comment: You should show that code.

Comment: I had shown in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is mostly unnecessary. In particular, this line makes no sense:

```
user.set_password(user.password)
```

This takes the already-hashed password and hashes it again. So now it will never validate on authentication.

You should remove most of this code. The forms do it for you already. You should just have:

```
    if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
        user = user_form.save()
        profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
        profile.t_teacher = user
        profile.save()
        return redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

Daniel Roseman this is code
form.py
'''

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    password1=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Enter Password'}),label='Password')
    password2=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Confirm Password'}),label='Confirm Password')
    class Meta:
        model= User
        fields= ('username','first_name','last_name','email',    'password1', 'password2',)
        widgets={
        'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'First Name'}),
        'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Last Name'}),
        'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Username'}),
        'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Email'}),
        }
class Profile(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= Teacher
        exclude=['t_teacher']
        labels= {'t_gender':'Gender','t_departmant':'Department'}
        widgets={
        't_gender': forms.Select(choices="gender_list",attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        't_departmant': forms.Select(choices="department_list",attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

'''
view.py
'''

```
def Reg_View(request):
    registered = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegisterForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form=Profile(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.first_name=user_form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
            user.last_name=user_form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
            user.email=user_form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            user.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()
            name=User.objects.get(username=user.username)
            p_save=profile_form.save()
            p_save.refresh_from_db()
            p_save.t_gender = profile_form.cleaned_data.get('t_gender')
            p_save.t_departmant=profile_form.cleaned_data.get('t_departmant')
            p_save.t_teacher=name
            p_save.save()
            registered = True
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            print(user_form.errors, profile_form.errors)
    else:
        user_form = UserRegisterForm()
        profile_form=Profile()
    return render(request,'Login_app/regform.html',{'user_form':user_form, 'profile_form':profile_form ,'registered':registered })
```

'''